# Java Chiper RSA/ECB/nopadding

Tags: go, rsa

I have such a code in Java:

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/nopadding");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getRSAPrivateKey());
```

and he decrypt my message.
How can I decipher my message in Go?

Comment: Hi, Go has a [RSA library](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/), did you check it out?

Comment: Yes, i check  DecryptOAEP(), Decryp(), DecryptPKCS1v15().
lways a mistake crypto/rsa: decryption error